# React updates the state when the app is hosted on GitHub Pages, but not when it's on localhost (or CodeSandbox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, github-pages

I've experienced a very strange behavior. This is my React app:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const buttonsObject = [
  {
    press: "q",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Clap%201.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "w",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Clap%202.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "e",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Conga%20High.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "a",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Conga%20Mid.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "s",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Conga%20Low.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "d",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Cowbell.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "z",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Hihat%20Open.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "x",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Mid%20Tom.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
  {
    press: "c",
    source:
      "https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine/blob/main/src/sounds/Pop%20Chord%201.mp3",
    name: "",
  },
];

//get raw file from github as source and set the name of each button
let nameRegEx = /.+\/(.*)\.mp3$/;
for (let i = 0; i < buttonsObject.length; i++) {
  buttonsObject[i].name = decodeURI(buttonsObject[i].source).match(
    nameRegEx
  )[1];
  buttonsObject[i].source = buttonsObject[i].source + "?raw=true";
}

const handleKeyPressWrapper = (setTextFunc) => {
  return (e) => {
    try {
      document.getElementById(e.key.toUpperCase()).currentTime = 0;
      document.getElementById(e.key.toUpperCase()).play();
      let name = "Loading";
      for (let i = 0; i < buttonsObject.length; i++) {
        if (buttonsObject[i].press === e.key) {
          name = buttonsObject[i].name;
          break;
        }
      }

      setTextFunc(name);
    } catch {}
  };
};

const dbHandleClickWrapper = (setTextFunc) => {
  return (e) => {
    const customkey = e.target.attributes.customkey.value;
    const button = buttonsObject[customkey];
    const id = button.press.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById(id).currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById(id).play();
    setTextFunc(button.name);
  };
};
const DrumButtons = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id="db-wrapper">
      {buttonsObject.map((elem, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="drum-button" key={i}>
            <button
              key={elem.press}
              className="drum-pad"
              customkey={i}
              onClick={dbHandleClickWrapper(props.changetext)}
              id={elem.name}
            >
              <span className="front">{elem.press.toUpperCase()}</span>
              <audio
                key={elem.press.toUpperCase()}
                id={elem.press.toUpperCase()}
                src={buttonsObject[i].source}
                className="clip"
              ></audio>
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Display = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id="display">
      <div id="display-text">{props.text}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

let listenerAttached = false;
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ text: "Press a button" });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", state);
  });
  const changeDisplayText = (text) => {
    console.log("state change function called", text);
    setState({ text: text });
    console.log("new state", state);
  };
  if (!listenerAttached) {
    document.addEventListener(
      "keydown",
      handleKeyPressWrapper(changeDisplayText)
    );
    listenerAttached = true;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App" id="drum-machine">
      <Display text={state.text} />
      <DrumButtons changetext={changeDisplayText} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click a button, the state of the App component changes by calling the `changeDisplayText` function. The `useEffect` function will get called and you can see the log in the console (and the display text changes). If I press a key on the keyboard, the `changeDisplayText` function will be called, but it won't change the state and the `useEffect` function won't get called too.

However, if I create a deployment build of the same app using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) and [this tutorial](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) and host it on GitHub Pages, it miraculously works, and I've no idea why.

Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/Julian-Sz/FCC-Drum-Machine

Here is a link to the page on gh-pages: https://julian-sz.github.io/FCC-Drum-Machine/

I've copied the repository to a CodeSandbox and look - it doesn't work again. Why does it work on GitHub Pages, and why not on localhost?

Here is a link to that CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fcc-drum-machine-from-github-tybqs

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows 10, version: 91.0.4472.77

Comment: It's working. State is updating and the audio is playing in Codesandbox

Comment: But not when you press keys on the keyboard. The audio is playing, but the text "Press a button" does not change. On GitHub Pages, the text is changing.

Comment: I don't have a proper explanation for this, but you need to move your `if (!listenerAttached)...`  code inside a `useEffect` which has an empty dependency array (so it runs only one time)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fcc-drum-machine-from-github-forked-qq1wz?file=/src/App.js:3724-3927

i think i know why. on your first render, it attaches the event handler, and marks your listenerAttached to true. Now since this code for attaching the event listener is inside the component body, it is run on every re-render and react thinks the listener is attached (which it is not). so your code fails. putting the handler inside a useEffect makes sure that the code only runs on initial mount. still doesn't explain why it works on gh pages.